# What is a null placeholder in PagedList?

Tags: android, pagedlist, android-jetpack

I've been trying to figure out what a null placeholder is in paged list in Jetpac components. Specifically, the docs say:

> ```
> boolean enablePlaceholders
> ```
>
> Defines whether the PagedList may display null placeholders, if the 
>       DataSource provides them.

on here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedList.Config#enableplaceholders

But i'm not sure what that means? I can't see a difference when i set this to true vs false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that if the `DataSource` that drives the `PagedList` provides positional info (position, list size), then whether the pagedlist is allowed to return `null` if the item is within range, but not yet loaded.

This allows you to render empty placeholder views if the user scrolls to an unloaded area, instead of being forced to limit scrolling until the adapter knows if the requested items actually exist.

Comment: So, i am using `PageKeyedDataSource`, and as such, i'm imagining that this provides positional info. I've set the page size to be very small (so to make sure there are a lot of unloaded items). but even then, i don't notice a difference, and the adapter's `onBindViewHolder`, where i invoke `getItem(position)`, still does not return null when i fling/scroll really fast. is there a better way to surface this null? (i'm setting `enablePlaceholders` to be true)

Comment: You could simulate it by adding a delay to your data source. If `getItem` isnt returning null it means your datasource has already provided the data. Keep in mind that it loads past the bounds of the list to avoid having to directly show after requesting a load.

Comment: oh you know what. you're talking about the data source being something like database, right? i've tried this with network-backed data source, and i can't get a null for the life of me. i think the database will give the empty items first, then load the actual content for each item later. network is different because it's batched. is that the right understanding?

Comment: It is only relevant after the initial load. A `DataSource` provides a list of data and the actual size of the data domain, if you try to access an item which it hasn't cached yet then it'll return `null`. Not being able to trigger it means the caching/preloading is working as intended.

Comment: it works if you set `itemsBefore` and `itemsAfter` in the `LoadResult.Page` constructor